# How can i start node typescript process (Express API) in background?

Tags: node.js, typescript

I have a express API i need to start this process in background to continue when i close the connection (Ubuntu Server - Terminal)

```
node --inspect -r ts-node/register server.ts
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In regards to NodeJS applications, [check out `PM2` to run, and automatically restart your application in the event of a crash or system reboot](https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/quick-start/).

```sh
npm install -g pm2
pm2 start server.js
pm2 save
pm2 startup
```

Generally in production, you should be utilizing your transpiled JavaScript, instead of TypeScript directly, hence my use of `server.js`, but [nothing stops you from integrating TypeScript with PM2](https://pm2.io/docs/runtime/integration/transpilers/).

---

For a more broad answer, `screen` can be used to run processes in the background. This should be installed by default, if not run: `sudo apt install screen`

Using screen:

- Run `screen -S <session_name>` to open a new session, press `SPACE` to push through the licensing gibberish.
- Start the desired processes in your screen session.
- Press `CTRL` `A` then `CTRL` `D` to detach from the session; this will continue to run even if you close your terminal.
- Run `screen -r <session_name>` to return to your screen session, `screen -list` lists all active screen sessions.
- Press `CTRL` `D` or run `exit` in a screen session to terminate it.

[View the manpages for more details.](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/groovy/en/man1/screen.1.html)